How does CMPXCHG affect FLAGS register?
Intel official documentation says:

The ZF flag is set if the values in the destination operand and register AL, AX, or EAX are equal; otherwise it is cleared. The CF, PF, AF, SF, and OF flags are set according to the results of the comparison operation.

However in "art of assembly language" by Randall Hyde it says that only ZF flag is affected. And indeed in DOSBox only ZF flag gets affected.
Did Intel change something for newer processors?

Also the AMD manual says flags are set according to result and my ryzen 1700x does set them.

The Intel manuals have a different description for cmpxchg and cmpxchg16b.  The former supposedly sets these flags, the other does not.

To state the obvious, DOSBox is an emulator and its behaviour might not be the same as any real hardware, if its authors were looking at a book other than Intel's manuals.  (And/or if Intel's old manuals were wrong!)

I see. DosBOX does not change flags register after XCHG instruction either and I think it was stated by the author somewhere that this is because XCHG is a rare instruction. He said there are more urgent issues than building support for it.

@famesyasd or maybe because XCHG really does not affect flags?

Skylake (i7-6700k) cmpxchg sets other FLAGS the way cmp eax, r/m8 would have, matching what Intel's manuals say (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cmpxchg).  (If testing yourself, remember that cmpxchg updates EAX on not-equal, so copy EAX somewhere else if you want to run a cmp after cmpxchg to see that the FLAGS don't change again.  https://godbolt.org/z/n14746q98)

@Jester I mistyped. I meant XADD instruction, not XCHG.

The documented behavior of CMPXCHG, ever since the 80486 when the instruction was first introduced, has always been to set flags according to the result of the comparison.  See the 80486 Programmer's Reference Manual (large PDF).
So it seems that this is an error in Hyde's book, and a bug in DOSBox.
As fuz notes, CMPXCHG8B and CMPXCHG16B are different and they only set ZF, leaving the other flags unaffected.  So it's possible that Hyde and/or the DOSBox implementers mistakenly assumed CMPXCHG was the same.

The OP reports in comments the DOSBox doesn't update FLAGS after xadd (also new in 486).  It's well known that unlike Bochs, DOSBox doesn't aim for the most faithful emulation, primarily aiming for just enough to be compatible with games and other real software.  (Although usually that means details of hardware outside the CPU, somewhat surprised that DOSBox wouldn't bother to fix bugs where a single instruction doesn't update FLAGS the way the manuals document even after it's reported.)

Yeah, it seems to me that it took them more work to write a message explaining why they don't want to fix it, than it would have taken to just fix it.

Yeah.  Not like the code-size or emulation-speed cost would have been significant, especially for a rarely-used instruction (in DOS programs).
